# Width of a Button Inside a UIStackView

Tags: ios, uikit

I have a UIStackView and it displays an UIImageView and a UIButton in vertical alignment. UIImageView will take the complete width of the parent view and the UIButton will be a constant width of 100.

```
// add button to the screen
        let button = UIButton(configuration: config, primaryAction: UIAction() { [weak self] _ in
            
            // do something 
        })
    
     
        
        
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        // NOT WORKING - THE BUTTON RENDERS AS THE WIDTH OF THE VIEW TAKING THE WHOLE WIDTH OF THE SCREEN
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
        
        stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -200).isActive = true
        stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
       
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
```

[image]

How can I control the width of the UIButton to be 100?

Answer (score 3):

You must Add Button to another UIView and after that, you should add the view (which contains your button) to Stackview

your button must have constraint.

```
        let buttonContainerView = UIView()
        buttonContainerView.addSubView(button)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(buttonContainerView)
        view.addSubview(stackView)
```

Comment: Good solution!!

Comment: Why does the button needs to be added to a container view?

Comment: vertical stack view set a width for all components that contain. and also horizontal, the components have equal width

Comment: Thanks! I actually solved the problem by setting stackView.alignment to center. The button now looks nice and fine.

Comment: I think you have some constraint that you can't set it with center alignment, because of I couldn't see your all parts of code. good luck